# Google Ads не дает рекламу

Tags: php, wordpress, google-ads

Вирусы заразили хостинг и теперь Google Ads не дает рекламу, показывает ошибку - "Отклонено: Вредоносное или нежелательное ПО". В хостинге появляется файлы вроде как "5lvsd0zn.php " и я удаляю их, но они все равно появляются.

Еще Google Ads отправил мне письмо, которое показывает вредоносные линки на домене — `bakireklam.az`. Я не могу найти эти линки в файлах сайта:

> I have checked your website for malicious and unwanted software. These
> are the links that the system has found. Here they are:
> http://app7756.ruliday48.life/3681668004/?t=main9_5a04fe6b0821fe6b892d6e04db&u=d29pte4&o=vxzkpbg&f=1,
> http://app7756.ruliday48.life/?utm_campaign=bKMuT7EMVXU5Z6UvvSHONGlfu-yV43iC8T8uYixAFxs1&t=main9_5a04fe6b0821fe6b892d6e04db,
> http://app7756.ruliday48.life/cookie/js.cookie6.js,
> http://app7756.ruliday48.life/media/mainstream/bbms.js,
> http://app7756.ruliday48.life/media/mainstream/jquery.js,
> http://app7756.ruliday48.life/media/mainstream/ru/desc/winner-survey/135399247_1.png,
> http://app7756.ruliday48.life/media/mainstream/ru/desc/winner-survey/alert.ogg,
> http://app7756.ruliday48.life/media/mainstream/ru/desc/winner-survey/app.css,
> http://app7756.ruliday48.life/media/mainstream/ru/desc/winner-survey/bootstrap.min.css,
> http://app7756.ruliday48.life/media/mainstream/ru/desc/winner-survey/bootstrap.min.js,
> http://app7756.ruliday48.life/media/mainstream/ru/desc/winner-survey/font-awesome.min.css,
> http://app7756.ruliday48.life/media/mainstream/ru/desc/winner-survey/logo.png,
> http://app7756.ruliday48.life/media/mainstream/ru/desc/winner-survey/news.png,
> http://app7756.ruliday48.life/web/,
> http://realcenter-mobileapps2.com/?url=I4WHKFughjLLjFWYiA2amuybx6lcSvfQmpzo1BNnf2M2hYBdqVpgr4yDCBSu%2BbN%2FbYifPfTEOQ6TMr90N5mrkmd9PrGbRpbi5rB%2F6Ep8pxsi6KIUysZ4eQ%3D%3D,
> http://realcenter-mobileapps2.com/away.php,
> https://pushanert.com/custom,
> https://pushanert.com/ntfc.php?p=2480981&r=sw,
> https://pushanert.com/ntfc.php?p=2480981&ucis=true&m=https&nbinp=true&var=null&ymid=9c6e0b35-6c66-4e87-af24-7db2fc2a9fb4,
> https://robotcaptcha.info/afjhjk7647gfgaj.js?v=3.1.29&o=1f700fb49d3c48388d0a441678df6f4c&pub=0&p=2480981&trace_id=d5b39a0d-90b7-4d28-ae1c-ba5974ac52f7,
> https://robotcaptcha.info/age2/images/arrow-v2.png,
> https://robotcaptcha.info/age2/images/arrow.png,
> https://robotcaptcha.info/age2/images/loader.gif,
> https://robotcaptcha.info/age2/index.html?cid=9c6e0b35-6c66-4e87-af24-7db2fc2a9fb4,
> https://robotcaptcha.info/age2/js/push-subscriber.js,
> https://robotcaptcha.info/age2/js/trls.js,
> https://robotcaptcha.info/favicon.ico,
> https://tdsjsext1.com/ExtService.svc/getextparams

Comment: Ну и как вам помочь? Лечите вирусы

Comment: Антивирус не может найти вирусов.

Comment: Плохой антивирус, значит. Поставьте плагин Wordfence и проведите сканирование. Если и после этого заражение будет повторяться, уходите с этого хостинга.

Comment: напишите администрации хостинга, пусть проверяют наличие дыр на своей стороне

Answer (score 1):

1. Скачайте все файлы с сервера на локальный комп.
2. Проверьте все файлы антивирусом (разными).
3. Установите текстовый редактор типа Visual Studio Code (в нем точно это есть), откройте папку с файлами сайта и устройте поиск по вхождениям, которые вы ищете (адресам вредоносных сайтов).
4. Если есть старый бэкап сайта, то сравните папки пофайлово, по размеру или по содержанию - найдете проблемные файлы - это поможет на будущее.

Удачи!

Answer (score 0):

Тут нет волшебной пипетки, Вам нужно каким либо способом избавиться от вредоносного кода. Больше чем такого рода советами Вам тут помочь не смогут.

Comment: Яже сказал в файлах сайта нет вредоносвого кода. Я просто хотел узнать каким способом можно найти вирус